# Ubuntu default page on 443 port instead node.js app

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, node.js

I'm trying to display node app on 443 port with SSL but server shows me default ubuntu page all the time. I've set redirect from 80 port to 443 and it's working fine.

Node app is working on 3000 port and I can access it from  http://myapp:3000.

I try use iptables but nothing happens:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

I use Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu Server (Apache2). I've set 80 and 443 ports in Amazon Security Groups.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have the HTTP web server configuration set up, but have left the HTTPS web server configuration as the default.  Adjust the settings for the SSL `VirtualHost` (presuming Apache) to match that for the standard one, notwithstanding the additional settings for SSL support.

Comment: In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf I have set something like: [link](https://codepaste.net/9hozec)

Comment: And I ask again: notwithstanding the additional configuration to enable SSL, is this identical to your other configuration?

Comment: What you mean? Please be more detailed, I'm a really beginner. What files should I check?

Comment: Compare the non-comment lines of `000-default.conf` and of `default-ssl.conf`.

Comment: default-ssl.conf is above and 000-default.conf [here](https://codepaste.net/rhj4bh)

Comment: Maybe should I use some proxy?